# Why `declare -p VAR` returns "declare -- VAR" on an unset local variable but gives an error "bash: declare: A: not found" on an unset global variable?

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, variable, function

I don't understand:

```
$ declare -i VAR=0; \
> echo "$A"; \
> fun() { local -i VAR=1; echo {; echo "$VAR"; declare -p VAR; unset VAR; echo "$VAR"; declare -p VAR; echo }; };\
> fun; \
> echo "$VAR"; \
> declare -p VAR; \
> unset VAR; \
> echo "$VAR"; \
> declare -p VAR;
0
{
1
declare -i VAR="1"

declare -- VAR     # <-- no error message
}
O
declare -i VAR="0"

bash: declare: VAR: not found  # <-- error message
```

Why does calling `declare -p VAR` give different results? I mean, I understand that in one case `VAR` is a global variable whereas in the other it is local. But could the result have been anticipated from some deeper understanding of some "mechanics" behind?

If not, is it on purpose that `declare -p` gives different results here? And if so why?

Comment: You'll probably not find my "explanation" satisfactory (that's why I'm not answering), but here's something about "mechanics": in `func(){ local v; ...; unset v; v=12; }`, people would **not** expect that `v=12` set the global `v` variable (and would consider it very broken if `unset` would work as if it were called `unlocal` ;-)), so the `local` should still keep shadowing the global variable inside the function, even after it was unset. Notice that `declare -- VAR` inside a function (without the `-g` option) is identical to `local -- VAR`.

Comment: ... so the `declare -- VAR` output of `declare -p VAR` is correctly informing you that `VAR` is **still** a local variable, even after you have unset it.

Comment: Interesting observation. You might want to ask for a canonical explanation on one of the bash mailing lists: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/

Comment: @user499944 Indeed, I also think the shadowing is still at play, but I could not see a good reason why it should be so. I expected to "unshadow" the global variable. But you make a very fine point!